# How to fix mongoose Model.create being stuck forever

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I can't figure out why mongoose can't complete this Model.create.

same connection works fine with other controller functions

[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIUT2.png)

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPita.png)

i am trying to create a new document but my code just gets stuck
and i cant get any error to figure out whats wrong

```
const createNote = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { user, title, text } = req.body

    if (!user || !title || !text) {
        return res.status(400).json({ text: 'all fileds are required' })
    }
    console.log('got here')
    const userId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user)

    const newNote = await Note.create({ user: userId, title, text })
    console.log("got here 1")

    if (!newNote) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'note not created' })


    }

    res.status(200).json({ message: `new note created for ${user} ` })
}
catch (e) {
   console.error("error handling note creation: ", e);
    res.status(500).send()
}
}
```

```
const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
 user: {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   required: true,
   ref: 'User',
 },
 title: {
   type: String,
   required: true,
 },
 text: {
   type: String,
   default: true,
 },

 completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
},
{
 timestamps: true,
}
);

noteSchema.plugin(autoIncrement, {
inc_field: 'ticket',
id: 'ticketNums',
start_seq: 500,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```

Comment: Please post snippets of code rather than screenshots. It's important that all critical information is preserved in the text of the question as external links can go dead. It's also helpful to be able to paste your code into my editor to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest handling the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you can try and figure out what is going on.

Comment: I actually do think he's using the promises correctly. `await model.create()` is exactly the way the function is called in the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.create() Also, the function `model.create()` returns a promise natively, so his `await` certainly isn't "making it a promise"

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

So I can't see your schema for Note, but I assume that the `user` field is supposed to have the type `Ref<User>`, which is to say a reference to a `User` model that you have defined elsewhere. But in the sample of code you provided, it would appear you gave it a mongoID string.

If you add the following line the script should start working. This converts your user variable from a string representation of an mongo ObjectID to a true mongo ObjectID. :

`user = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user);`

However, I think your main problem is actually just that you didn't get an error print out. My guess is that the `asyncHandler` made the error disappear. If you put the body of your function inside a try catch block with a console.error in the catch, you should be able to see that error in the future

```js
const createNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res)=>{
    try{

        // your code here

    } catch(e){

        console.error("error handling note creation: ", e);
        res.status(500).send()

    }

})
```

This is mostly guesswork since I don't have a lot of context. If this doesn't solve it, please post what the schema is for your `Note` model and any error printout you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 

bth of your assumptions are correct tho i still get the same reaction if i wrap user with new mongoose.Types.Objectid. 
and still i stay stuck on sending request even after gettingr id of catchasync

Comment: @Ziv try removing your auto-increment plugin